# Dialogflow: creating intents with user inputs as a context

Tags: dialogflow-es

My question is about the creation of intents in Chatbots using the Dialogflow platform.

I would like to know if it is possible to create **intents** with **contexts** based on a user inputs.

By the regular way in Dialogflow we have to define the contexts "by hand" in the moment of creation of it.

I have read the DF documentation and I did not find a solution for that.

The scenario is:

When the user says "I want to plot **feature_1** and **feature_2**". I need these two features as output contexts, but for doing this, I have to define this intent with this **two** output contexts, the problem appears when I have a hundred of features, should I create a hundred different intents?

Thank you very much for any help.

Comment: have you created entities for all your features?  i.e. feature_1, feature_2, etc.

If so you can add entities to contexts.  Otherwise you can create contexts dynamically through the fulfillment webhook [0] or client API[1]

[0]https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/api-v2/rest/v2beta1/WebhookResponse#FIELDS.output_contexts
[1]https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/api-v2/rest/v2beta1/projects.agent.sessions.contexts/create

Comment: Yes, I had created the entities for all my features. About the creation of contexts dynamically, can we just do this with API v2?

Comment: yes: https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/api-v2/rest/v2beta1/projects.agent.sessions.contexts/create

Answer (score 0):

You can setup intents as requiring an input context which can be provided either from a previous intent or by adding them to the queryParameters of your request.  For example:

**Intent #1 - "I want to plot feature_1 and feature_2"**
`feature_1` and `feature_2` would be defined as entities/an entity(list) and included in the parameters list of the intent.
and an output context for this intent (ie `plot-features`)

**Intent #2 - "Use option_x"**
 - set this intent to require and input context of `plot-features`

you can reference context values directly in an intent using `#context-name.valueName`. For example in the text response:

```
Okay #user-context-data.Name what option would you like to use for the plot?
```

would return as:

> Okay Bob what option would you like to use for the plot?